How to fetch a token for MS Graph given a resource with the `User.Read` scope in its list of configured permissions using Azure CLI?
After having preauthorized the Azure CLI for an application object (resource), I often use the following command to fetch a token for the preauthorized scope(s), e.g. user_impersonation:
az account get-access-token --resource api://779d25c3-6c74-4875-b5ae-ef9b5a04b1e8

Now consider the case, where I have configured the resource with permissions for e.g. MS Graph User.Read.
In that case, I would like to use Azure CLI to fetch a token for MS Graph, with User.Read scope, via the resource, like I would normally do using the authorization code grant flow: sign-in to the resource and specify a scope of e.g. User.Read.
Is that possible?
